# Rails 5 don't precompile JS files with ES6 code in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, uglifier

I am deploying an app with some javascript that contain ES6 code.

When I did run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, I got:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())
```

This is because prueba.js has the following:

```
var greetings = () => {
  let saludo = 'tio';
  console.log('saludo' + saludo)
};
greetings();
```

And Uglify don't recognize ES6. For fix this, I had installed and setting the gems:

```
gem 'sprockets-es6', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'babel-transpiler', '~> 0.7.0'
```

But isn't working,

In application.rb, I have:

```
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require 'sprockets/es6'
```

Note: If i run `rake assets:precompile` without RAILS_ENV=production, I don't get errors

Comment: I think you need to add `.es6` to the file extension for Sprockets to run the JS through babel.

Comment: @max I changed for a .es6 extension, but I got other error: 
`ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using ES6, if you use uglifier (3.2.0)
you can change the file production.rb

with config.assets.js_compressor = **Uglifier.new(harmony: true)**

Comment: It worked!, just update de Uglifier version, thanks @adcosta

Comment: Apparently versions above 3.2.0 still show the same error, even with changes mentioned above.. Had to downgrade to 3.2.0 to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer worked till now but precompile with ES6 and uglifier compression stopped working after the release of new version execjs 2.8 after doing bundle update a few days back.

ERROR: JSON::ParserError: 439: unexpected token at '{"code":"/*! ...

To make it work again just had to fix the version of execjs to 2.7

Comment: I have just upgraded to rails 5.1 and what solve for me was upgrading execjs to 2.8.1